# Read only file system after reformatting and repartitiniong

Tags: external-hard-drive, mbr, bad-sectors, read-only, filesystem-corruption

I am facing some issue in my one of hardisk. I have cleaned it completely, scanned it for bad sectors and reformatted it but again it giving me readonly file system error on next day.

Here is pastebin for dmesg https://pastebin.com/p1zZmZjh

Comment: What does a SMART test show?

Comment: SMART test run successful without any error